# Terminate android service without reset

Tags: android

I am aware that force killing an app is very bad, but the client requires it. I am required to implement a force reboot of sorts for the app. This is how I implemented it:

I create a `BroadcastReceiver` in my Application's (not Activity's) `onCreate` method. I have it wait for the REBOOT command to be broadcast. Upon receipt, I have it broadcast another message that has the services call `stopSelf` so that threads and services have a chance to exit cleanly. I then have an `AlarmManager` call my main activity 5 seconds later. Finally have my application kill itself with `Process.kill(Process.myPid())`. For the most part, it works, and I just need to add some extra waiting time before it kills the process (maybe by waiting for a TERMINATE broadcast from each running Service). My issue is this: while reviewing the logs, I found out that the system schedules the services to reboot. I'm worried about conflicts. Is there a way to terminate the services without any chance of it rebooting?

Comment: This is strange. Are you saying that the system is restarting Services that voluntarily killed themselves (via stopSelf())? Are these STICKY services?

Comment: No, at the time, the services were being killed with the process, so it was registering as a crash. I wasn't waiting for the services to harakiri. I made an answer, but I really would appreciate your input on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by having the Receiver wait for all the services to finish their `onDestroy()` calls before having it die. I also changed from `Process.kill()` to `ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses()`.

*As a side note: I know it's wrong, but it really does feel cool killing the processes hehehe.*